# Is the name of the .ipa file important?

Tags: ios, ipa

When I distribute an iOS app to the app store I have to upload a .ipa file. Is it important what the name of the .ipa file is? Must the name be unique? Or can you give the .ipa file every name you want?
When I download an app from te app store the .ipa file is visible in iTunes and the file is saved on disk. This assumes that the filename must be unique or will apple make it unique in case another file with the same name already exists?

Answer (score 3):

The filename of the uploaded IPA is irrelevant.

When the user downloads the app, the filename is always the bundle ID. So either iTunes Connect doesn't store the initial filename (which is what I would guess) or it is renamed somewhere inside their system.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using the XCode and Application loader for uploading the app, we don't want to specify the file name for the ipa. I think apple is managing that part.

Also two apps can't have same name, so somehow apple is changing the ipa name to it's product name.